# Trying to download the stream gives a file with content of "Resource id #xxx"

Tags: php, laravel, csv

I'm using Laravel, and am trying to export items in my database to a CSV file. I am getting pretty close. Unfortunately, I get an output of `Process id #xxx` in the downloaded file.

This is a more minimal and anonymous example of the code I've been using.

```php
public function exportCSV(): StreamedResponse
{
    $keys = ['id', 'title'];
    $posts = Post::select($keys)->get();

    $stream = fopen('php://memory', 'w+');
    fputs($stream, "sep=,\n"); // Excel will be nice
    fputcsv($stream, $keys);

    foreach ($posts->toArray() as $post) fputcsv($stream, $post);

    rewind($stream);

    // dd(stream_get_contents($stream)) gives the expected result here
    return response()->streamDownload(function () use ($stream) {
        echo $stream;
    }, 'export.csv');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is because in your $stream variable is just a handle.
To read data from the handle you need to use the fread function.

```
$handle = fopen('php://memory', 'w+');
[..]
$blocksize = 1024;
while (($block = fread($handle, $blocksize)) !== false) {
  echo $block;
}
fclose($handle);
```

The loop is needed because you have to define a count of bytes to read. When the end of the file is reached fread returns false.

For more information see the PHP documentation:
https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.fread.php

Comment: accurate answer. Another option is `fpassthru`, and you can eliminate the while loop.

Comment: I did not know the stream was a handle. Thanks for letting me know. I've decided to go with fpassthru().